# Java applet ignoring getWidth()

Tags: java

I'm trying to build a pyramid in Java using GRect. I use getWidth() to position the pyramid in the center of the canvas but it tends to trip the left part of pyramid.

I'm learning programming through [CS106A](http://see.stanford.edu/see/courseinfo.aspx?coll=824a47e1-135f-4508-a5aa-866adcae1111) and using Java 1.6 so tried to get some other peoples code and they too showed the same bug. I tried to draw a simple rect and it works fine.

Is it some issue with Java applet as it tends to ignore getWidth() value at all. I used println(); to get getWidth() value and it works.

```
    import acm.graphics.GRect;
    import acm.program.GraphicsProgram;

    public class Pyramid extends GraphicsProgram {

    /**
     * eclipse generated SVUID
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5703830460071233096L;

    /** Width of each brick in pixels */
    private static final int BRICK_WIDTH = 30;

    /** Width of each brick in pixels */
    private static final int BRICK_HEIGHT = 12;

    /** Number of bricks in the base of the pyramid */
    private static final int BRICKS_IN_BASE = 14;

    public void run() {
        //centering the pyramid
        int _canvasWidth = getWidth();  //canvas width
        //println(_canvasWidth);    //to check if getWidth returns a value
        int _brickSpace = BRICKS_IN_BASE * BRICK_WIDTH; //space consumed by the base row
        int _freeSpace = _canvasWidth - _brickSpace;    //empty base level space
        int _xOffset = _freeSpace / 2;  //x for left most brick of base row

        for(int row=0; row<BRICKS_IN_BASE; row++){  //the row number
            int _rowTab = (BRICK_WIDTH/2) * row;    //indentaion for each row
            int _brickInRow = BRICKS_IN_BASE - row; //bricks as per row
            for(int _brickNumber=0; _brickNumber<_brickInRow; _brickNumber++){  //placing bricks till _brickInRow
                int x = (_xOffset + _rowTab) + (_brickNumber * BRICK_WIDTH);
                int y = (BRICK_HEIGHT * (BRICKS_IN_BASE - row));    //y as per row num
                GRect _brick = new GRect(x, y, BRICK_WIDTH, BRICK_HEIGHT);  //creating brick instance
                add(_brick);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it draws the pyramid at the centre at first, but the problem comes up when I resize the viewer window.
The point is Java applets have an inherited method called `public void paint(Graphics g)` that is called whenever the applet has to be painted. Resizing the viewer window is one of the cases that makes the paint method called.

So, to fix this you need to override the paint method, ie. add such a method:

```
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
    this.run();
    super.paint(g);
    }
```

This method will be called every time the window is resized. But remember you don't need multiple pyramids so add following line to your `run` method to remove all the previous bricks before adding the new ones.

```
    removeAll();
```

Comment: i tried `public void paint(Graphics g) {
    this.run();
    super.paint(g);
    }` but I got two pyramids, on the left side my old tripped pyramid and then to its right a centred one. [This is what my original code does](http://snag.gy/SXLtR.jpg) and this [after Graphics g](http://snag.gy/j2pJV.jpg) On my system even before the window is resized the pyramid is tripped. No effect of resizing.

Comment: And you have the `removeAll();` line at the beginning of the `run` method?

Comment: you got me. I was placing `removeAll();` after `run(){}`.... that was the mistake... so silly of me. Ya the code works now even with resizing. [Thanks](http://ctrlv.in/173552) :)